# Accessing getState of another RTK Query createApi in another prepareHeaders?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-redux, redux-toolkit, rtk-query

The [official documentation](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/rtk-query/api/fetchBaseQuery#setting-default-headers-on-requests) shows how to access an `auth` slice in `prepareHeaders`. I would like to do the same except that I do not have a slice but the auth "state" is fetched and saved using RTK Query's `createApi`.

```js
import { fetchBaseQuery } from '@reduxjs/toolkit/query'
import type { RootState } from './store'

const baseQuery = fetchBaseQuery({
  baseUrl: '/',
  prepareHeaders: (headers, { getState }) => {
    const token = (getState() as RootState).auth.token

    // If we have a token set in state, let's assume that we should be passing it.
    if (token) {
      headers.set('authorization', `Bearer ${token}`)
    }

    return headers
  },
})
```

The `auth`'s `token` comes from a **slice** here (see https://github.com/reduxjs/redux-toolkit/blob/6f0b3f1a72d7f6a39eb9585adba9eb3ef7277a58/examples/query/react/authentication/src/features/auth/authSlice.tsx#L7):

```js
type AuthState = {
  user: User | null
  token: string | null
}

const slice = createSlice({
  name: 'auth',
  initialState: { user: null, token: null } as AuthState,
  reducers: {
    setCredentials: (
      state,
      { payload: { user, token } }: PayloadAction<{ user: User; token: string }>
    ) => {
      state.user = user
      state.token = token
    },
  },
})
```

However, in **my case** the token is stored in a state "slice" created by **`createApi`** not `createSlice`:

```js
import { createApi, fetchBaseQuery } from "@reduxjs/toolkit/query/react";

type KeycloakResponse = {
  access_token: string;
};

export const keycloakApi = createApi({
  reducerPath: "keycloakApi",
  baseQuery: fetchBaseQuery({ baseUrl: "/redirect" }),
  tagTypes: [],
  endpoints: (builder) => ({
    getKeycloakAccessToken: builder.query<KeycloakResponse, void>({
      query: () => `/?info=json&access_token_refresh_interval=0`,
    }),
  }),
});
```

How would I access this `access_token` in `prepareHeaders`?

If I try it with `getState()` I cannot access it?
[image]

How can I access its `accessToken` in another createApi `prepareHeader`?

Answer (score 1):

Try :

```js
prepareHeaders(headers, { getState }) {
  const state = (getState as typeof store.getState)();
  const {
    keycloakApi: { access_token },
  } = state;

  headers.set("token", access_token);
  return headers;
},
```